# React stack navigation , how to pass state without routes

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have four components A,B,C,D. Each of these components have its local state.

These are stacked using react stack navigations

Now i like to pass on each of the local states in A, B and C to the last component D.

I do not need to give routes. I already have routes onPress using prop.navigation.navigate, that takes me from A to B to C to D.

I just need to pass state of A directly to D, B to D and C to D?

Thanks
sal

Comment: Can you put the local state in a shared ancesotr?

Comment: i am new in react and have no idea what that is :). just googled it, this will be complicated solution. these components were written independently and it would require lot of changing.

Comment: Show the code that you have tried up until now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Final Output:**

[image]

Here is how you can pass the states from A, B, C to D.
You just need to pass the state of the parent as a parameter to the next Screen route while navigating to it, then you can access those parameters with the help of `route`.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function A({ navigation }) {
  const [fromA, setFromA] = useState('From A');
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>A Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to B"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('B', { fromA: fromA })}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function B({ navigation, route }) {
  const [fromB, setFromB] = useState('From B');
  const { fromA } = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>A Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to C"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('C', { fromA: fromA, fromB: fromB })}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function C({ navigation, route }) {
  const [fromC, setFromC] = useState('From C');
  const { fromA, fromB } = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>A Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to D"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('D', { fromA: fromA, fromB: fromB, fromC: fromC })
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function D({ navigation, route }) {
  const { fromA, fromB, fromC } = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>D Screen</Text>
      <Text>From Screen A: {fromA}</Text>
      <Text>From Screen B: {fromB}</Text>
      <Text>From Screen C: {fromC}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="A">
        <Stack.Screen name="A" component={A} />
        <Stack.Screen name="B" component={B} />
        <Stack.Screen name="C" component={C} />
        <Stack.Screen name="D" component={D} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Live App Example on [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/getting-started-%7C-react-navigation?platform=android&name=Getting%20started%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.8.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.9.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.9.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.0.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.15.1&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fnew-screen.js)

You can read the full documentation here: [Passing parameters to routes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params)

Comment: thanks Ketan. Sorry for not providing the code , as they are too long. Yes it should work. some more conceptual questions. All the three components A,B,C have lot of state variables. this makes the code bloated. if i copy all the states from one component to another?but it should work. Second your opinion, i like to apply redux from component D, as A, B,C are user interface i do not wish to use redux there. Does this seem right strategy?thans

Comment: if you have a lot of data that is needed to be shared between many components then using state management be it redux, context is advisable. PS: I don't quite enjoy working with redux :P. I find it very complex to wrap my head around most of the time.

Comment: in all the four components, the data is not shared. at component D, which would be submit component, the data only needs to be sent to the database. So A, B, C dont share data. I am brining data from A, B , C to D for implementing redux at D level, But data is not shared

Comment: So the current solution should work without any problem.